# How do I bind an Image dynamically in XAML?

Tags: c#, silverlight, image, mvvm, binding

The following displays an **image** correctly in a **silverlight** usercontrol:

```
Image image = pagingManager.BaseApp.DatasourceManager.GetImage("helloWorld1");
ContentArea.Content = image;
...
<ContentControl x:Name="ContentArea"/>
```

However, I want to **dynamically** bind the image to **XAML**, e.g. like this:

```
#region ViewModelProperty: MainImage
private Image _mainImage;
public Image MainImage
{
    get
    {
        return _mainImage;
    }

    set
    {
        _mainImage = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("MainImage");
    }
}
#endregion
...
MainImage = pagingManager.BaseApp.DatasourceManager.GetImage("helloWorld1");
```

And my **XAML** is this but the result is that it shows **nothing**:

```
<Image Source="{Binding MainImage}"/>
```

**What do I need to put in my XAML to make it display the image object I have in my ViewModelProperty?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Image.Source` property is of type `ImageSource`, so your ViewModel should expose an `ImageSource`. `Image` is a control, it has nothing to do in the ViewModel.

If you *do* expose an `Image` control in your ViewModel (which is definitely a bad idea), then you should display it in a `ContentControl`, not an `Image` control :

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding MainImage}" />
```

Comment: But this is a silverlight app and the DataManager has already loaded all the images the app needs to use, so I want to just pull the Image object out of the DataManager collection and hook it up to the XAML, I don't want to pass a datasource and then have XAML continually loading it, I just want it to display the Image object that happens to be contained in the MainImage variable, is there not a way to do that, or do I need to have a Refresh() method in my code-behind and manually reattach the Image object to a ContentControl each time the image changes?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question... Did you see the last part of my answer (perhaps you posted your comment before I edited it) ? Binding the content of a ContentControl should work. If it doesn't, try that : `<Image Source="{Binding MainImage.Source}"`

Comment: sorry, our comments criss-crossed, yes, that works perfectly, exactly what I was looking for